# Do the applications use less memory when they are moved to different displays?

Tags: macos, display

Last few days I am spreading everything to separate screens, and noticed that I have few more GB of RAM free this way. I use everything the same way as before.

Do applications use less memory when they are moved to separate displays?

Comment: Nice question. How are you measuring the ram? This nicely complements older questions like http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126148/are-number-of-desktops-affecting-memory and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15406/does-using-spaces-slow-down-the-system?lq=1

Comment: Thanks for the message. I'm using [Memory Clean](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memory-clean/id451444120?mt=12) for cleaning and monitoring the memory.